# About the proof of Cayley’s Theorem

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

I'm reading a proof of Cayley's theorem. In the following two snippets I want to know why it's needed(although it's apparently true) that $\pi_a\circ\pi_b=\pi_{ab}$ to prove that $G^*$ is closed under composition?

I meant, why not just said: Since $a,b\in G, ab\in G$ so by the construction of $\pi_a:G\to G$ clearly $\pi_{ab}\in G^*$.

[image: Cayley's theorem proof part 0]
[image: Cayley's theorem proof part 1]
[image: Cayley's theorem proof part 2]

At the end of the proof the equality is used, so I wonder whether the author just want to condense two steps into one? (I skip the part of $G^*$ is closed on its inverse)

[image: Cayley's theorem proof part 3]

Comment: But why must $\pi_{ab}$ be the output of $\pi_a \circ \pi_b$?  Oh wait, it is, because we just checked it.

Comment: Then what does your statement imply?

Comment: In other words, if we did not verify that equation, why would $G^*$ be closed w.r.t. the composition?

Comment: @xbh: Since the function $\pi$ is defined for all $G$ and $ab\in G$, so $\pi_{ab}$ in $G$, no equality is needed. This is what I meant.

Comment: It just shows that $\pi_a\circ\pi_b$ is a member of $G^*$ (because $\pi_g\in G^*$ whenever $g\in G$, right?). It happens that $g=ab$ does the trick. So the only reason to show that $\pi_a\circ\pi_b$ and $\pi_{ab}$ are the same thing is that is is obvious that the latter is in $G^*$; since they are the same, so is the former.

Comment: You also need this to show that the representation is a homomorphism.

Comment: Yeah, but are these enough for you to say that $G^*$ is a subgroup?

Comment: @MPW is getting to the heart of the issue:  $G^*$ needs to be closed under its operation of $\circ$ for any of the claims to make sense

Comment: @xbh: lol, I know what you meant, thank you! The equality links the composition to a element that's clearly in $G^*$...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that it is clear that $\pi_{ab} \in G^*$. But we want $G^*$ to be closed under the group operation of $G^*$, in which the product of $\pi_a$ and $\pi_b$ is defined to be $\pi_a \circ \pi_b$, not $\pi_{ab}$.

Once we prove that these two are equal - that $\pi_a \circ \pi_b = \pi_{ab}$ - then we know that $G^*$ is closed under $\circ$, precisely because we know that $\pi_{ab} \in G^*$.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $G^*$ is a subgroup of the *group of permutations on the set $G$* one should prove that for every $a,b \in G$ there is a $c \in G$ such that $$\pi_a\circ\pi_b=\pi_{c}$$

So the proof needs to provide a way to *choose* a $c\in G$ such that indeed $\pi_a\circ\pi_b=\pi_c$ holds. The element $c=ab$ is a natural choice.

The apparent complication with this subgroup stuff is due to the fact that the authors wanted to have $G^*$ as the image of the homomorphism, probably because they are interested to show that $\pi$ is an isomorphism.

A different approach could have been to see $\pi$ as an injective homomorphism from $G$ into the group of permutations on $G$ and then simply use that fact that the image of this homomorphism (namely $G^*$) is isomorphic to the starting group ($G$).
In this case one use the fact that the image of an homomorphism is a group to prove that $G^*$ is a group.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The author put homomorphism on the latter part of the book, so fortunately I don't know it and will learn it later, and thank you for the alternative.